# CoD Black Ops: Thunder Gun

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Is there any ammo for the thunder gun apart from the 12 shots when you unlock it?

Comment: Are you talking about the campaign or zombies?

Comment: I'm talking about the Campaign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only way to get ammo is to get the max ammo dropped by the zombies. Or pack a punch it to make the Zeus cannon, which will come with full ammo.

Same situation with any gun you can only get via the mystery box, unfortunately.